# Fetching SAML Response Spring MVC

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-saml

We are integrating SAML SSO in our Spring application using Spring Security.
Our application is hosted in Google App Engine.We are facing a issue, below are the steps,

Step 1: Requesting the URL of our application will redirect to idp login page
Step 2: After authenticating the credentials, idp sends response to our application

**issue:**
**Step 3: Our application once again sends request to idp and it continues infinitely.**

We are not able to catch the first response sent by the idp in our application, response sent by idp is appending "/saml/SSO" to out context path.

Please suggest on how we cound fetch the SAML response, or why our application is re-sending request to idp.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved. Problem was the Jetty Server . I deployed in Tomcat Server, now i able to receive the response. Is there a workaround for this problem in Jetty?.

Comment: Issue is not resolved yet. We have found that this issue is not related to any Web Server, Only when deployed in Google App Engine this reload issue occurs. Please sugggest how to stop this reload in Google App Engine.